# Algorithm for finding the value of determinant

Tags: algorithms, determinant

Okay I am writing to write a program which computes the determinant of a matrix. So is there an algorithm that allows you to do that ?

**Are there any other ways of finding the determinant value other than finding its co factors ? Anything involving plain binomial expansion ?**

Comment: I assume you are asking for any generic $n \times n$ matrix, yes?  For a $3 \times 3$ matrix you could use [The rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)

Comment: @CSCFCEM Yes nxn matrix. Anything that can be programmed easily ?

Comment: @CSCFCEM Rule of Sarrus works great for 3x3 but what about nxn ?

Comment: looks like a similar question has been asked [here before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435133/what-is-the-best-matrix-determinant-algorithm).  You may be out of luck for something with binomial expansion, but perhaps someone else may know of a little known trick or something.

Comment: @CSCFCEM Wow. Thanks. But the L and U matrices will have the same order as the original matrix. How do you calculate their determinants ?

Comment: The nice thing about triangular matrices is that the determinant is just the product of the diagonals!!  See #6 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant)

Comment: @CSCFCEM Hmm thats true and thank you. But to find the LU matrices you need to do elimination operations if I am not wrong. How would you do that in a program ? This there an algorithm for that also ?

Comment: yea it seems like one of those problems where if you try to make it easier in one place, you complicate another part.  There are some algorithms [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Algorithms) for doing an LU decomposition.  Not sure if it'll be easier going from there.  Good luck!